# MySQL multi column match with multi row results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to mySQL and tried to solve this for a day. I tried to match data from column Want1 with Offer1, and Want2 with Offer2, 
but the Type need to also be matched with other uid. Each uid will have only either W or O in W/O (want/offer). Here is my table.

User table:

```
Id,  Want1, Want2, Offer1, Offer2, Type, uid, W/O
---  -----  -----  ------  ------  ----  ---  ---
1      a     null   null    null    KK    5    W
2    null      b    null    null    LL    30   W
3    null    null     a     null    KK    20   O
4    null    null   null      b     LL    13   O
5    null    null     a     null    BB    6    O
6    null    null     a     null    KK    70   O
```

Desired table result:

```
Want1, Want2, Offer1, Offer2, Type, uidW, uidO
-----  -----  ------  ------  ----  ----  ----
 a      null     a     null    KK     5    20
 null     b     null     b      LL    30    13
 a      null     a     null    KK     5    70
```

Is it possible to use pure SQL to get this result?

Comment: What happens to the 5th entry in your first table?

Comment: What happens to 5 also ?

Comment: The 5 entry is not match by Type (KK), so it was excluded.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: @Strawberry Would you mind telling me what is a better DB design for this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
SELECT w.want1,
       w.want2,
       o.offer1,
       o.offer2,
       w.Type,
       w.uid AS uidW,
       o.uid AS uidO
  FROM my_table w LEFT JOIN
       my_table o ON (IFNULL(w.want1, 'x') = IFNULL(o.offer1, 'x') AND
                       IFNULL(w.want2, 'x') = IFNULL(o.offer2, 'x') AND
                       w.type = o.type)
 WHERE w.wo = 'W' AND
       o.wo = 'O';
```

Output

```
want1   want2   offer1  offer2  Type    uidW    uidO
a   (null)  a   (null)  KK  5   20
(null)  b   (null)  b   LL  30  13
a   (null)  a   (null)  KK  5   70
```

Demo Here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1ff2e/20

Comment: Can I also use INSERT INTO with your solution? I want to copy the result to archive table.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular data:

```
select max(want1), max(want2), max(offer1), max(offer2),
       max(case when `W/O` = 'W' then uid end) as UID_W,
       max(case when `W/O` = 'O' then uid end) as UID_O
from t
group by coalesce(want1, offer1), coalesce(want2, offer2), `W/O`;
```

This assumes that one of the last two rows is really `'a', null, null`.

Comment: Thank you but what about uidW and uidO column?